# Using Karma to test javascript in a play 2.2.x application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, playframework-2.2

I've got a Play 2 application where my angular js dependencies (and possibly others) are declared using WebJars. When I serve up a page, I use the routing helper to fetch these javascript files.

If I want to test my javascript with Karma I need to specify the path to angular javascript files in order to run my angular dependent code. The examples I've seen on the web don't use web jars and just specify the path as ../app/assets/javascripts/lib/angular.js (or whatever). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you found a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: The workaround below works, but is awkward. We ended up abandoning web jars entirely and managing the entire javascript side of the application through npm/bower/etc. We wrote some sbt config to hook our test process into the main sbt testing workflow. It worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `playframework` and therefore I am not entirely understanding the restrictions it is bring to your JS Files but if this helps you can also do something like this in karma.cofig

```
files: [
    'http://localhost:91/sample.js'
],
```

I performed some quick tests and it worked fine.

Comment: That definitely helps but it's not exactly ideal because it requires the server to be running. This is not the end of the world, but it's awkward, especially if I want to create a javascript testing task in sbt